# How to get a certain output in Matlab without for loops?

Tags: matlab, optimization

I have a list of vertices where each row corresponds to a (x, y) coordinate.

For example, the following includes the vertices (0, 0), (1, 0), and (0, 1)

```
 V = [0 0;
      1 0; 
      0 1];
```

I also have a list of edges where the first column specifies the row of the starting vertex and the second column specifies the row of the ending vertex.

For example, the following includes the edges (0, 0) to (1, 0) and (0, 0) to (0, 1)

```
E = [1 2; % V(1) -> V(2) = (0, 0) -> (1, 0)
     1 3] % V(1) -> V(3) = (0, 0) -> (0, 1)
```

I need to produce a list of edges with their actual coordinates from these two lists. That is, from `V` and `E`, I need

```
 edge1 = [0 0]; % = E(1, 1) = V(1)
 edge2 = [0 0]; % = E(2, 1) = V(1)
 edge3 = [1 0]; % = E(1, 2) = V(2)
 edge4 = [0 1]; % = E(2, 2) = V(3)
```

I know how to do this with for loops, but my supervisor said there is a more optimal solution using the function `find(x)`, which returns the nonzero indices in an array. I do not see how this could be done with `find`. Is there a way that this could be done without using for loops but using the `find` function?

Comment: Isn't `edge1` just the first coordinate of the actual first edge, and so on? Is that intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I remember `find` is not really recommended when it comes to runtime, and for loops are not as bad as they where in the past taking JIT into consideration and MATLAB's effort to improve them.
However one possible solution without using for-loops (and without `find`) would be:

```
E = [1 2;
     1 3];
V = [0 0;
     1 0; 
     0 1];

Edges=V(E(:),:)

Edges =

 0     0
 0     0
 1     0
 0     1
```

So the output is not a list of different variables / edges but rather a matrix holding all of them row-wise.

Comment: For a representation of `E` with the inserted, actual coordinates from `V`, one could use `reshape(V(E, :).', size(E, 1), 2 * size(V, 2))`.